# With Native Client (NaCl) is it possible to embed a server in a page that can accept incoming requests?

Tags: google-chrome, networking, network-programming, google-nativeclient

Is it possible to open a port using Native Client that other browsers can connect to?  Like a browser to browser connection?

Answer (score 4):

In general, no. NaCl does not allow programs to open sockets directly (that would be a security problem). It is intended that NaCl/Pepper applications have the same general capabilities as  Javascript applications; so something like WebSockets (connection back to the server) would be supported, but not directly opening files or sockets on the client machine. There's some work going on to have a P2P style networking in HTML5 (e.g. http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/WD-html5-20080122/#peer-to-peer) which would likely get Pepper support as well, but I don't know what the status of that is.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to get P2P connection in browser is through WebRTC. If NaCl allows to use WebRTC (though Pepper API or whatever) then the only thing you need besides implementation is broker server that will connect clients with each other. See [PeerJS](http://peerjs.com/) for some info.